# Oracle SQL - Generate aggregate row using select

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate

I have a table like below.

```
|    FILE   | CATEGORY1 | CATEGORY2 | CATEGORY3 |
| File1.txt |    3      |     2     |     6     |
| File2.txt |    4      |     7     |     3     |
| File2.txt |    3      |     1     |     1     |
```

Now, Is it possible to add a new row as part of select query which will provide the below row added to the resultset.

```
| Total     |    10     |     10    |     10    |
```

**Expected final output:**

```
|    FILE   | CATEGORY1 | CATEGORY2 | CATEGORY3 |
| File1.txt |    3      |     2     |     6     |
| File2.txt |    4      |     7     |     3     |
| File2.txt |    3      |     1     |     1     |
| Total     |    10     |     10    |     10    |
```

Any help on achieving the above results is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
SELECT FILE, CATEGORY1, CATEGORY2, CATEGORY3 From TestTable
union all
SELECT 'Total', Sum([CATEGORY1]), Sum([CATEGORY2]), Sum([CATEGORY3]) From TestTable
```

If values in your column allow nulls, then can use function like `nvl`.

You can also try `rollup` also:

```
SELECT File, Sum([CATEGORY1]), Sum([CATEGORY2]), Sum([CATEGORY3]) From
TestTable
group by rollup (File);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have another query similar to the above one.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54644206/oracle-sql-generate-aggregate-rows-for-certain-rows-using-select

Would be helpful if you can consider checking that as well. Thank you.