# Oracle SQL - Generate aggregate rows for certain rows using select

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate, rollup

I have a table like below.

```
|FILE| ID |PARENTID|SHOWCHILD|CAT1|CAT2|CAT3|TOTAL|
|F1  | A1 |  P1    |     N   | 3  | 2  | 6  | 11  |
|F2  | A2 |  P2    |     N   | 4  | 7  | 3  | 14  |
|F3  | A3 |  P1    |     N   | 3  | 1  | 1  | 5   |
|F4  | LG1|        |     Y   | 6  | 3  | 7  | 16  |
|F5  | LG2|        |     Y   | 4  | 7  | 3  | 14  |
```

Now, Is it possible if I want to find the total (ie) aggregate of cat1, cat2, cat3 & total only for rows which has showChild as 'Y' and add that to the resultset.

> |Tot| Res | Res |     N   | 10  | 10  | 10  | 30  |

**Expected final output:**

```
|FILE| ID |PARENTID|SHOWCHILD|CAT1|CAT2|CAT3|TOTAL|
|F1  | A1 |  P1    |     N   | 3  | 2  | 6  | 11  |
|F2  | A2 |  P2    |     N   | 4  | 7  | 3  | 14  |
|F3  | A3 |  P1    |     N   | 3  | 1  | 1  | 5   |
|F4  | LG1|        |     Y   | 6  | 3  | 7  | 16  |
|F5  | LG2|        |     Y   | 4  | 7  | 3  | 14  |
|Tot | Res|  Res   |     N   | 10 | 10 | 10 | 30  |
```

Here I have added the Tot row(last row) after considering only the rows which has showchild as 'Y' and added that to the resultset.

**I am trying for a solution without using UNION**

Any help on achieving the above results is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use a union:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT "FILE", ID, PARENTID, SHOWCHILD, CAT1, CAT2, CAT3, TOTAL, 1 AS position
    FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Tot', 'Res', 'Res', 'N', SUM(CAT1), SUM(CAT2), SUM(CAT3), SUM(TOTAL), 2
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE SHOWCHILD = 'Y'
)

SELECT "FILE", ID, PARENTID, SHOWCHILD, CAT1, CAT2, CAT3, TOTAL
FROM cte
ORDER BY
    position,
    "FILE";
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Thank you for your response. 

For simplicity, I had given like taking from a single table whereas in my scenario, I have the table content in a large subquery. So if I use union it will be like using the subquery two times to generate the result.

Comment: Then you asked the wrong question.  I have answered the actual question you asked.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `UNION`

```
select FILE,ID ,PARENTID,SHOWCHILD,CAT1,CAT2,CAT3,TOTAL from table1
union 
select 'Tot','Res','Res','N',sum(cat1), sum(cat2),sum(cat3), sum(total)
from table1 where SHOWCHILD='Y'
```

Comment: This won't generate the output which the OP is expecting though.

Comment: I am trying for a solution without UNION

Answer (score 0):

I see you already accepted an answer, but you *did* ask for a solution that did not involve `UNION`.  One such solution would be to use `GROUPING SETS`.

`GROUPING SETS` allow you to specify different grouping levels in your query and generate aggregates at each of those levels.  You can use it to generate an output row for each record plus a single "total" row, as per your requirements.  The function `GROUPING` can be used in expressions to identify whether each output row is in one group or the other.

Example, with test data:

```
with input_data ("FILE", "ID", PARENTID, SHOWCHILD, CAT1, CAT2, CAT3, TOTAL ) AS (
SELECT 'F1','A1','P1','N',3,2,6,11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'F2','A2','P2','N',4,7,3,14 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'F3','A3','P1','N',3,1,1,5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'F4','LG1','','Y',6,3,7,16 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'F5','LG2','','Y',4,7,3,14 FROM DUAL )
SELECT decode(grouping("FILE"),1,'Tot',"FILE") "FILE", 
       decode(grouping("ID"),1,'Res',"ID") "ID",
       decode(grouping(parentid),1, 'Res',parentid) parentid, 
       decode(grouping(showchild),1, 'N',showchild) showchild, 
       decode(grouping("FILE"),1,sum(decode(showchild,'Y',cat1,0)),sum(cat1)) cat1, 
       decode(grouping("FILE"),1,sum(decode(showchild,'Y',cat2,0)),sum(cat2)) cat2, 
       decode(grouping("FILE"),1,sum(decode(showchild,'Y',cat3,0)),sum(cat3)) cat3, 
       decode(grouping("FILE"),1,sum(decode(showchild,'Y',total,0)),sum(total)) total 
from input_data
group by grouping sets (("FILE", "ID", parentid, showchild), ())
```

> ```
> +------+-----+-----+----------+-----------+------+------+------+-------+
> | FILE | F2  | ID  | PARENTID | SHOWCHILD | CAT1 | CAT2 | CAT3 | TOTAL |
> +------+-----+-----+----------+-----------+------+------+------+-------+
> | F1   | F1  | A1  | P1       | N         |    3 |    2 |    6 |    11 |
> | F2   | F2  | A2  | P2       | N         |    4 |    7 |    3 |    14 |
> | F3   | F3  | A3  | P1       | N         |    3 |    1 |    1 |     5 |
> | F4   | F4  | LG1 |  -       | Y         |    6 |    3 |    7 |    16 |
> | F5   | F5  | LG2 |  -       | Y         |    4 |    7 |    3 |    14 |
> | Tot  | Tot | Res | Res      | N         |   10 |   10 |   10 |    30 |
> +------+-----+-----+----------+-----------+------+------+------+-------+
> ```